# Flutter : What is the maximum weight of global variables?

Tags: flutter, performance, memory, mobile, global-variables

Good morning all,

I'm looking to know how variables are stored in a flutter application. I don't really know the world of mobile, so I'm a little lost. I'm on a project in which I have to store information when launching the application, which I retrieve via an API (they are then deleted when the user closes the application). Currently, the amount of data is reasonable, but I would like to know how much data I can temporarily store in my application (10kb? 10mo?), what are the risks with this way of doing things, does it have slow down the app...

I couldn't find anything on the flutter doc (https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/memory - At the time of writing this message, the line returns to an empty page with the letters TBD). I couldn't find any articles explaining the specifics of memory, performance related variable storage, related to flutter.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is "10mo"?  Do you mean "10 MB" (10 megabytes)?

Answer (score 0):

The Dart compiler used by Flutter is actually very good at optimizing code, so variables have almost zero overhead.

Having said that I must add that using *global variables* is not a good way of storing data in any kind of software. I suppose you select a suitable [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) technique to handle your data.

Regarding the amount of data, I don't think 10mo will be too much on a modern mobile device, but as always, ymmv.